# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Context Root Not Found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I created an application using worklight 6.0. after I build and deploy open the console I get

> Context Root Not Found

I checked the worklight.properties file and added the port number there(10080)...  but still I can't get the application viewed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context root by default is the name of your Worklight project.

1. If you want to "manually" reach Worklight Console in your browser, then make sure to follow the correct URL structure, which is: `http://host:port/contextroot/console`. For example: `http://localhost:10080/myFirstApp/console`
2. You can also open Worklight Console via Eclipse:

   - Right-click on the Worklight project and choose "Open Worklight Console"...
   - By default this will open the console *inside* Eclipse; you can change this behavior via `Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser`
3. No need to edit `worklight.properties` or any other file; this works as-is out-of-the-box

Comment: Hi I am having same issue; I have installed worklight server liberty version in my XP machine and deployed one war file in it, with context-root as ‘test’ and also configured mysql db and application center too.
Now when I visit http://localhost:10080/test/console , it does not open any page. However when I open http://localhost:9080/ URL in my machine. It shows me attached screen shot.
So could you please guide me that in order to open IBM Worklight console through worklight server liberty version ( and not eclipse). Reference Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydodwkuj8k2xxkl/9080%20page.JPG